# Group by Count - Number of Repetitions

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table like below,

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | Sample1 |
| A | Sample2 |
| A | Sample3 |
| B | Sample3 |
| B | Sample1 |
| C | Sample2 |
| C | Sample3 |
| D | Sample1 |

If I group the table by Name to get the count,

```
Select Name, Count(*) as count from table group by Name;
```

I will get the following result,

| Name | count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 1 |

I need to get the number of repetitions of each count. Means desired outcome below,

| count | numberOfTimes |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Toss your existing sql into a subquery and group once again:

```
SELECT ncount, count(*) numberOfTimes
FROM (Select Name, Count(*) as ncount from table group by Name) dt
GROUP BY ncount
```

Comment: Yes. I thought the same. Is it possible without a subquery?

Comment: Anytime you have to aggregate an aggregate you will need a subquery. Window functions give you some options, but it's a 50/50.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT(*)` window function in your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS count,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COUNT(*)) AS numberOfTimes
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY Name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/hEoS0K9O).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Any idea how to write this in LINQ? I belive we have to use group by